# How to ovewrite two key values in unix

Tags: shell, unix, compare

I am having two files. Need to compare two files and overwrite the values from test2.txt to test1.txt by unix unix shell script.
If anything Extra keys that should be added in test1.txt

Note: Need to overwrite only values not keys.

test1.txt

```
Name = krishna
Age =30
DOB = 30-Sep-94
Total Marks =375
```

test2.txt

```
Name = Ram
Age =35
DOB = 23-Aug-95
Total Marks =300
Remarks = He is very good
```

Expected o/p

Test3.txt

```
Name = krishna
Age =30
DOB = 30-Sep-94
Total Marks =375
Remarks = He is very good
```

Comment: Do you mean to add only the extra keys to the test1 file or also update all the keys in test1 that were found in test2?

Comment: @Abishek Aditya Yes. Correct.

Comment: I want an answer to this, do you want to do
a) add only the extra keys to the test1 file,
 or
b) add the extra keys to the test1 file and also update all the keys in test1 that were found in test2. Reply with a or b

Comment: I need o/p of b) add the extra keys to the test1 file and also update all the keys in test1 that were found in test2.

Comment: Can you please help me out!!!

Comment: Does @JamesBrown's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *="}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print ($1 in a?a[$1]:$0)}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
Name = krishna
Age =30
DOB = 30-Sep-94
Total Marks =375
Remarks = He is very good
```